# 2 column format in Rmarkdown fails after opts_chunk

Tags: r, markdown

I have reproduced a simple example of what I am facing in a long markdown script.

I would like some plots on slides to appear in 2 column format and some in 1 column format. Accordingly I need to adjust the width of the plots. trouble is the 2 column format does not seem to work when I open the resulting HTML in Chrome browser ; the charts appear one below the other.

The Rmd (saved using "Presentation" -> default Output Format "HTML ioslides") is below:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Gaurav Chaturvedi"
date: "6/29/2016"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

<style>
  .col2 {
    columns: 2 200px;
    -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
    -moz-columns: 2 200px;
  }

</style>

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(knitr))
boxplot(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars)
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA,  fig.height = 4, fig.width = 4)
```

## 2 Plots 

<div class = "col2">
```{r, echo=FALSE}
boxplot(mpg ~cyl, data=mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,])
boxplot(mpg ~cyl, data=mtcars[mtcars$cyl==6,])
```
</div>
````

Answer (score 1):

If you change the css in to:

```
<style>
 .col2 {
 float:left;
}
</style>
```

Your 2 plots will float aside each other (in the div-element). When I replicate your example in Chrome, it worked as you would like.

Comment: I added the "float:left;" in the current <style> (top of Rmd)? It did not work

Comment: Did you remove the 'columns: 2 200px' parts as well?

Comment: NO i didn't. I just appended the "float:left" to the end. Is that correct?

Comment: Remove the columns part from your css styling. Only keep the <style>
 .col2 {
 float:left;
}
</style>. That worked for me.